# How to fix edge width not properly working

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to write python code where I want to be able to change the width of each edge.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# create Graph

g = nx.Graph()

# add nodes to graph

g.add_node(1)
g.add_node(2)
g.add_node(3)
g.add_node(4)
g.add_node(5)
g.add_node(6)
g.add_node(7)
g.add_node(8)
g.add_node(9)
g.add_node(10)
g.add_node(11)
g.add_node(12)
g.add_node(13)
g.add_node(14)
g.add_node(15)
g.add_node(16)
g.add_node(17)
g.add_node(18)
g.add_node(19)
g.add_node(20)
g.add_node(21)

# add edges between nodes

g.add_edge(1, 2,width=1)
g.add_edge(1, 3,width=10)
g.add_edge(2, 3,width=10)
g.add_edge(3, 4,width=10)
g.add_edge(4, 5,width=1)
g.add_edge(5, 6,width=10)
g.add_edge(5, 7,width=10)
g.add_edge(6, 7,width=10)
g.add_edge(5, 9,width=10)
g.add_edge(6, 9,width=10)
g.add_edge(7, 8,width=10)
g.add_edge(6, 10,width=10)
g.add_edge(10, 11,width=10)
g.add_edge(6, 11,width=10)
g.add_edge(11, 12,width=10)
g.add_edge(9, 10,width=10)
g.add_edge(9, 15,width=10)
g.add_edge(10, 13,width=10)
g.add_edge(12, 13,width=10)
g.add_edge(13, 14,width=10)
g.add_edge(14, 16,width=10)
g.add_edge(15, 14,width=10)
g.add_edge(9, 14,width=10)
g.add_edge(16, 17,width=10)
g.add_edge(13, 18,width=10)
g.add_edge(17, 18,width=10)
g.add_edge(17, 20,width=10)
g.add_edge(17, 19,widht=10)
g.add_edge(19, 20,width=10)
g.add_edge(18, 20,width=10)
g.add_edge(19, 21,width=10)
g.add_edge(20, 21,width=10)

widths = list(nx.get_edge_attributes(g,'width').values())



# position of nodes of Graph
pos={
    1:(13,78),
    2:(24,87),
    3:(23,77),
    4:(25,68),
    5:(27,59),
    6:(27,46),
    7:(17,49),
    8:(5,36),
    9:(42,58),
    10:(40,36),
    11:(35,31),
    12:(40,12),
    13:(61,30),
    14:(70,43),
    15:(72,55),
    16:(82,40),
    17:(83,20),
    18:(77,15),
    19:(93,14),
    20:(88,9),
    21:(97,4),
}

# drawing graph and specifying properties(node color, edge color, line width, etc)
nx.draw(g, pos, with_labels=True,node_color="orange", node_size=300, edge_color="black", width=list(widths))


# The graph title and showing it
plt.title('Gabriel Graph (102)')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I have of all edge widths set to 10 except 2 but the output shows three edges with widths of 1.

Here is the link to the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/akgwo.png

Can someone help fix this?

Comment: You have a typo (width -> widht): `g.add_edge(17, 19,widht=10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comment above you have a typo. As a result, the list provided as the `width` argument to `draw` is one short. IMO, networkx should raise an error in this case but it doesn't. Instead, it uses a default width of 1, which is why your "last" edge (20, 21) is assigned a smaller width than specified.

Typos like this can be avoided if you avoid code repetition. I would construct the graph like this:

```py
import networkx as nx

# create Graph
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(range(1, 22))
g.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (4, 5)], width=1)
g.add_edges_from([
    (1  ,  3),
    (2  ,  3),
    (3  ,  4),
    (5  ,  6),
    (5  ,  7),
    (5  ,  9),
    (6  ,  7),
    (6  ,  9),
    (7  ,  8),
    (6  , 10),
    (6  , 11),
    (9  , 10),
    (9  , 14),
    (9  , 15),
    (10 , 11),
    (10 , 13),
    (11 , 12),
    (12 , 13),
    (13 , 14),
    (13 , 18),
    (14 , 16),
    (15 , 14),
    (16 , 17),
    (17 , 18),
    (17 , 20),
    (17 , 19),
    (18 , 20),
    (19 , 20),
    (19 , 21),
    (20 , 21),
], width=10)
```